# Column chart in ggplot2 using a categorical variable as fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

So I am analyzing a dataframe with students (removed), their class year (2020,2021,2022), and whether or not they recieved an interview. I would like to show graphically the number of students in each Class year who applied and who actually got the interview.

I tried coding this up but I received errors in a lot of my attempts which tells me I might not be approaching this correctly.

DATA:

```
app <- structure(list(Interview = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No"), Year = c(2021, 2021, 2020, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2020, 2022, 2022, 2021, 
2022, 2020, 2022, 2022, 2020, 2020)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = 
c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I then used dplyr and ggplot to group the data and plot accordingly
    library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(ggthemes)
    library(readxl)

```
 year_table <- app %>% 
   group_by(Year) %>% 
   summarize(number = n()) %>% 
   mutate(pct=number/sum(number)) %>% 
   arrange(desc(pct))
 year_table

 #interview candidates
 year_table_int <- app_int %>% 
   group_by(Year) %>% 
   summarize(number = n()) %>% 
   mutate(pct=number/sum(number)) %>% 
   arrange(desc(pct))
 year_table

 ggplot(data = year_table, mapping = aes(x = Year, y = number)) +
   geom_col(fill= "darkslategray3") + theme_economist() +
   ggtitle("Distribution of Applicants based on Class Year") +
   geom_text(data=year_table, aes(label=paste0(round(pct*100,1),"%"),
                                  y=number), size=4, vjust = -.5) +
   labs(y = "Number of Applicants")


 #Attempt 2
 a<- 1:200
 ggplot(year_table, aes(x=factor(Year), y=number)) +
   geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity",aes(fill=factor(Interview))) +
   coord_cartesian(ylim=c(50, 150)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=a[a%%10==0]) +
   xlab("Year") + ylab("Number of Applicants") + 
 scale_fill_discrete(name="Interview?") +
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=14))
```

I have confused myself at this point but  I have included a visual as to how I would like this to look. Maybe using geom_bar may be better??? Unsure, regardless I would like to show the Class year on the x-axis, the number (or count) on the why, and dodged bars indicating both total applicants and # who received an interview (Interview = Yes) .

https://imgur.com/a/Lan6HiN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you can style the plot yourself.

```
ggplot(app, aes(x = Interview, fill = Interview)) +
    geom_bar() + 
    theme_economist() + 
    facet_wrap(~Year) +
    theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Comment: I am attempting to show total number of applicants stacked next to only those who got the "Yes" vote. Your code only breaks it down by yes and no.

Comment: Edited, the answer, how about now?